# How to read .sh file contents into Python Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, shell

I have a file.sh where I'll have to consume contents from it. I created the subprocess but how do we go about reading the contents in it?

I just tried calling the subprocess but not known how to consume from it.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ENV=$1
echo "ENV "$ENV

if [[ "$ENV" = 'app1' ]]
then
                HIAPGHOST=10.102.30.11
                HIAPGPORT=5432
                HIAPGDB=db_name
                HIAPGUSER=username
                HIAPGPASS=password
                HIAPGSCHEMA=schema_name

elif [[ "$ENV" = 'app2' ]]
then
                HIAPGHOST=10.10.49.10
                HIAPGPORT=5432
                HIAPGDB=db_name
                HIAPGUSER=password
                HIAPGPASS=schema_name
elif [[ "$ENV" = 'app3' ]]
then
                HIAPGHOST=10.17.49.10
                HIAPGPORT=5432
                HIAPGDB=db_name
                HIAPGUSER=password
                HIAPGPASS=schema_name
else
                HIAPGHOST=10.48.42.10
                HIAPGPORT=5432
                HIAPGDB=db_name
                HIAPGUSER=password
                HIAPGPASS=schema_name

fi
```

```py
subprocess.call(['./file.sh'])
```

I want store the contents of .sh file as variables that I can pass later in my code and I expect the output to be something as

```
if "$ENV" == 'app1':
    host = 10.102.30.11
    port = 5432
    hiapgdb=db_name

elif "$ENV" == 'app2':
    host = 10.10.49.10
    port = 5432
    hiapgdb=db_name
```

etc.....

Comment: That script doesn't appear to produce  any output so there won't be much to *"consume"*. If you start a subprocess it starts a new process which does something then exits, so that isn't going to help much either. What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to pass those info such as host, port etc during creating the connection for the d/b. Also say if there is a Service that I've to call(`https://MSA/Data/POSAllRegionRefresh?refreshWHTable=N)` etc., passing the same into my further exercises.